# How to make a BIG stage with drag & flick inside a canvas using Pixi.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, gsap, pixi.js

I am learning a **PixiJS** to make an animation like this: **http://fetedelabiere.promo-agency.com/**.

I have already created a project environment. But I am struggling with making a big stage and having a drag / flick interaction in it like the one in the website mentioned above.

How should I make a BIG stage with drag & flick inside a canvas created using **PixiJS**?

Here is my JavaScript code so far:

```
var screen_width = $(window).innerWidth();
var screen_height = $(window).innerHeight();
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(screen_width, screen_height, {backgroundColor: 0xcccccc});
var stage = new PIXI.Container();
var texture = new PIXI.Texture.fromImage('images/pixel.jpg');
var bg = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);

$('body').append(renderer.view);
bg.position.x = 0;
bg.position.y = 0;
stage.addChild(bg);

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(stage);
}

animate();
```

I do not know how to:

- draw a 1:1 size background image. This image is more than **1920x1800** in dimensions.
- implement the drag & flick interactions if the image exceeds the viewport / screen size.

Thanks. Hopefully someone will provide me with some references.

Comment: Can [this](http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=5666) help you?

Comment: um, thanks your reference, but this tutorial can't help me unfortunately.